# jQuery - Drop down show/hide onclick - need to hide when clicking outside

Tags: jquery, menu, hide, show

I have a drop down menu working using the code below. It show/hides on click fine but I'm looking to get it to hide when I click outside of the menu also - can anybody assist, brain isn't working today?

```
    $( "li.dropmenu" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'selected' );

    if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'selected' ) ) {
        $( '.dropdown' ).show();
    } else {
        $( '.dropdown' ).hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $( "li.dropmenu" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( 'selected' );

      if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'selected' ) ) {
        $( '.dropdown' ).show();
      } else {
        $( '.dropdown' ).hide();
      } 
    });

    $(document).click( function(){
        $('.dropdown').hide();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Chj/268/)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work - the drop down doesn't even appear.

Comment: `$("body").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown").hide();
 });` Try this

Comment: having the click on the body hides it onclick so it never appears as the click to show is in the body the hide overpowers in the initial show

Answer (score 0):

Its old question but if anyone else has same problem, it can be resolved using click event. Idea is to leave the particular element using its id or class and make click on body.

```
    $('body').click(function(e){
        if($(e.target).attr('class')!=='dropmenu')
            $('.dropdown').hide();
    });
```

*I hope it helps*